# All my lines of code in my 'src' folder have errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image: Part of the code as seen in Eclipse]

Am having problems with development in android as all my lines of code in all the files in the src folder where am placing my java files have errors on them. I do not know where the problem is coming from!

First had problems where 'R' was underlined in red. then after Ctrl+Shift+O, I exited my eclipse and on opening it, that's what I saw on my java files

Comment: CHeck your imports.   OH .. and Android Development is moving to Android Studio (1.0 recently released).  You may want to look at moving to that.

Comment: Close and restart eclipse

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Really? I switched back to Eclipse!

Comment: Yes, Really.   The Android team will NOT do any future development of the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: actually the problem came after me tampering with my xml files but I've corrected all of them but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Project Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries tab
```

and make sure JRE is added, if not, click "Add Library..." and add it.

Comment: How come all my other projects don;t have the JRE and are running properly?

Answer (score 0):

All errors seems related to Android's specific classes:

- you may have a problem with you Eclipse+ADT installation
- you may have pasted the code into the wrong type of project
- you may simple missing the corrisponding import

Last is simplier to verify, just hover with mouse over the error and see if Eclipse suggests you to add a specific import

Comment: actually I've been coding and running my android applications on my phone normally until after running successfully when all this happened!